# Solve $(x^2+y^2+x)dx-(2x^2+2y^2-y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Its not homogeneous and I realized this is not exact DE and tried to find an integrating factor to make it exact. I tried the five possibilities as mentioned in morris-tennenbaum ordinary DE but none of them worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x^2+y^2+x)dx-(2x^2+2y^2-y)dy=0$$
For the integrating factor you can try 
$$\mu(x,y)=\dfrac 1 {x^2+y^2}$$
Then you have:
$$\partial_y \left(1+\dfrac x {x^2+y^2}\right)=\partial_x 
 \left(-1+\dfrac y {x^2+y^2} \right)$$

---

Here is another way to solve the DE:
$$(x^2+y^2+x)dx-(2x^2+2y^2-y)dy=0$$
Rearrange terms. 
$$(x^2+y^2)dx+ (xdx+ydy)-(2x^2+2y^2)dy=0$$

$$(x^2+y^2)dx+\frac 12 d(x^2+y^2)-(2x^2+2y^2)dy=0$$
Divide by $x^2+y^2$ 
$$dx+\frac 12 \dfrac {d(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}-2dy=0$$

Integrate.
$$x+\frac 12 \ln{(x^2+y^2)}-2y=C$$

Comment: does a integrating factor for this problem exist?

Comment: Yes  $\mu(x,y)=1/(x^2+y^2)$ is an integrating factor for this differential equation. Try and see @DhatriDongre

Comment: @DhatriDongre I added some lines I hope it's more clear now

Comment: how do you arrive at the integrating factor? was it a clever guess? clearly i am new at DE

Comment: Here i really guessed it...@DhatriDongre